# Recommend a drag and drop library for a react-admin dashboard?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, widget, react-admin

We have a dashboard that displays stats similar to the Posters Galore react-admin demo (https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/).

We'd like to find a way to allow the user to drag the widgets into a custom configuration.

Any thoughts on react libraries for drag and drop that would work well for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a little more research I've decided to try React-Grid-Layout.

https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout

It has the features I was looking for out of the box. Seems to use react-draggable and react-resizable under the hood.

I may still look at react-dnd if I can find some examples of people using it to build draggable boxes that snap in a grid pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **react-dnd** library. It's the best way to implement the drag ad drop method.
For your reference here I have mentioned the github code details,

**https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd**

Or you need a detailed instruction refer the below react-dnd about page,

**https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/about**

Please check the above mentioned url or you can check the react drag and drop libraries,

**https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-drag-and-drop**

**https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable**

Hope it will helps you. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, I did look at that but wasn't sure how hard it would be to implement a grid system with that. Have you tried that before? From the about page, "...leaving its visual aspects such as axis constraints or snapping to you." I guess I just wasn't sure how hard that would be.